# full-text search 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables. One stores video information, the other stores the tags associated with that video. They share the common field `vid_id`. I am trying to fulltext search both tables for matches. The goal is that if there is a match in either table, then all fields with that vid_id be gathered from video.

The problem is my query just crashes with `Call to undefined method PDOConnectionFactory::errorInfo()`. It should return one row since there is one entry in tags where name field = `test`. Anyone have any ideas? I have been struggling with this for a while.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `vid_id` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `vid_id` (`vid_id`,`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vid_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uploader` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

$sql = "SELECT video.*
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST('?') as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('?') as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
WHERE
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST('?') OR
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('?')
ORDER BY cscore DESC;";
$stmt4 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt4->execute(array('test','test','test','test')) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `print_r($conn->errorInfo())`?

Comment: Thanks then this is returned Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ). Still no query results. What does that even mean lol?

Comment: Add this before your "prepare": `$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` and then try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing a comma (,) after `SELECT video.*` in your SQL query.

**Working example:**

```
SELECT video.*,
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST('?') as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('?') as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
WHERE
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST('?') OR
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('?')
ORDER BY cscore DESC;
```

Comment: HEY! Francois thanks for the input. The error is gone but I didn't get any results however. Do you know why that could be? I tried querying names that exist video.title and I also tried names that exist in tags.name without luck...

Comment: Nvm I am now searching in Boolean mode and I have been reading about all the kinks here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html.

Comment: @Scarface - Sorry. I left to watch a movie. I'm glad to hear you figured it out.